# Where are automatically created App ID's etc kept?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

When I set up a new Xcode project, the App ID and certificates are all made and updated automatically. Where are these then visible? They do not appear in my developer account.

Previously I have always created new provisioning profiles and App ID's through the developer portal then manually placed these into my apps, however I want to know how this works automatically?

Is it a case that they don't need to appear anywhere and that the app can be archived, validated and uploaded as normal? and if so when you create a new app in iTunes connect and have to select an App ID will it appear?